# Equivalent focal length of two mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection, telescopes

I have two concave mirrors of the same size, both with $f=1.5\ \text{m}$.

I would like to build a setup to increase the focal length, i.e. have a setup with a focal length of around 6 m. How do I calculate this equivalent focal length of a two-mirror system? I found [this formula](https://www.telescope-optics.net/two-mirror.htm) online:
$$
f = \frac{f_1 f_2}{f_1 - f_2 - s}
$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the focal lengths of the two mirrors and $s$ is the distance between them. Is this formula correct? I am a little confused with the signs. I believe both $f$ are positive, as I have a concave mirror, but is $s$ positive or negative?
Also, where will the principal plane be?

Here's an image of the mirror arrangement I have in mind:

[image]

(I know that the setup will be eccentric, but I would neglect the effect of that.)

Comment: How do you intend to arrange the mirrors?

Comment: @Farcher In a sort of "Z" shaped configuration. I guess the second mirror needs to be further than the first's focal length.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the arrangement.